# Please define the full path to lint.py in the settings

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am trying to configure sublimer for python, when installing pylinter I always get this error:

"please define the full path to "lint.py" in the settings.

Even tried a full uninstall...

By the way, also sublimerope - extract method doesnt work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed pylint? Ya gotta install pylint separately.

HT to hernamesbarbara for actually making my answer useful.

Comment: Just to add some more to this answer, you can install pylint via pip. `pip install pylint`. Then you can discover the full path to pylint by running python, importing pylint. then do `pylint.__path__`. Copy that into the Pylinter.sublime-settings file.

Comment: To add to @hernamesbarbara response, once you identify the path to pylint installation, your pylinter.sublime-settings should include something like `{
    "pylint_path" : "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pylint"
}`

Comment: thanks for @rajagp , his comment really helped me , I'm using mac and add the following line on default settings pylint_path" : "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint

Answer (score 1):

ok, after reading previous comments and answers I decide  to add an improvement :

1. after installing pylint in Sublimetext You need to install pylint directly from to your python environment
   for my python 2.7 i use the following command :

   pip install pylint
2. after  installing pylint you need to find his path as suggest by @ hernamesbarbara  comment use this to find it :

   pylint.**path**

PS: for my mac i found it here :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint
```

3. Once you are sure that pylint is installed in python and you know the exact path you need to add that path to sublime text settings as follow :

   Preference > Package settings>pylinter>settings-Default

(mac users can refers to  [image: this image])
,
and open the json file and then add the followings line at the end of the file
:

```
"pylint_path" : "/path/to/pylint/installation/"
```

for mac user you can just add :

```
"pylint_path" : "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint"
```

Hope this is clear ....